# Redirecting Issue - Site working fine in desktop but redirecting on mobile

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Hi everyone this is my WordPress site http://xtensionbar.com/ this is working fine in desktop view but when i do open it on phone it redirects me to another website. I try to find out code on .ht-access file, index file, header file, functions file or everywhere i can find even in my database too but found nothing. I Google it but not found any helpful solution. Any suggestion what could be the reason for this

Comment: You have external js from facebook, maybe it's the problem in external js code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like malware.  Either site code is compromised or plugins your site makes use of are.  An example of why WordPress has a poor reputation.  Bad Plugins.

See these posts:

- https://www.malwareremovalservice.com/googleframe-malware/
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mobile-version-only-redirecting-to-spam

Check the deployed code against your source.  Then I would try deactivating all plugins. If that resolves the issue, reactivate each one individually until you find the cause.

Only related post on SO I find is the following: [Can't find the script redirecting mobile traffic in WP self-hosted site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845278/cant-find-the-script-redirecting-mobile-traffic-in-wp-self-hosted-site).  Note / Keyword: redirection seems to pass through **`googleframe.net`**.

Also consider changing what I hope is just place holder text for your `<title>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have found my solution the error is in .htaccess file

Comment: And you understand how your .htaccess file was modified and how to prevent it?

Comment: Yes there was a code which was redirecting my website